# Tengo un problema con el metodo subString();

Tags: java, jframe, caracteres

```
    String caden = "", txtf = "";
    int txt = 0, since = 0, until = 0;
    
    caden.valueOf(jLabel1);
    txt = caden.length();
    
    txt = txt - 1;
    
    txtf = txt.substring(since , until);
```

El error que me aparece es

> Int can not be conferenced

para m es extraño, pues yo ya habia
trabajado con Length antes, y no me aparecia el mismo error, segun yo, el error es que un Int (Since, until) no pueden ser convertidos por el subString, ayuda, gracias!

Comment: Yo pensé que te diría algo más feo por tratar de sacar una subcadena de un entero

Comment: Lo que estás haciendo está mal, el substring se aplica a cadenas de texto, no a números, pq mejor no dices que es lo que deseas hacer para así ayudarte mejor

Comment: Intento hacer una calculadora basica, asi que quise hacer el Boton de DEL, para borrar un numero que se habia puesto, asi que mi idea era usar una cadena de texto, puesto que los numeros estan dentro de un JLabel, y poner -1 a la cadena, algo asi intento

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hola al parecer jLabel1 no regresa un valor yo cambiaria la linea

```
    caden.valueOf(jLabel1);
```

por esta:

```
    caden = jLabel1.getText();
```

Y cuando hagas el substring

```
    txtf = txt.substring(since , until);
```

Debes hacerlo desde la poisicion 0 hasta la posicion txt -1, solo te falto asignarlo en la variable until:

```
    until = txt -1
```

El codigo completo seria este:

```
    String caden = "", txtf= "";
    int txt = 0, since= 0, until = 0;
    
    //caden.valueOf(jLabel1.getText());
    caden = jLabel1.getText();
    txt = caden.length();
    //txt = txt - 1;
    until = txt - 1;
    txtf = caden.substring(since , until);
```